# Change XCode's code autocomplete format

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos

Is it possible to change the Xcode autocomplete format for functions? For instance when I type `-tableView` in a class that receives `UITableViewDataSource` methods and hit autocompletion it inserts for instance this:

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Now I am crazy about code formatting and just something like this `-(NSInteger) tableView` is enough to drive me nuts because I want my code to look consistent and the same. So I have to correct all the methods back to `- (NSInteger)tableView`.

Can I change this somehow, so that it's insertet "correctly" in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can change it. I believe XCode 3 just indexes the header file and use what it has found there as an autocompletion entry. Editing the header files, removing a few spaces in the declarations might help.

But the only effective way would be to file a bug report to Apple.

You should check how XCode 4 behaves first, though. It's now available on the developer page.

Comment: Yep, I'm already running on XC4, and it seems to do it *right*. XC4 actually adopts the style you use when hitting autocompletion (when you type `-method` it inserts `-(void)method...` and when you type `- method` it inserts `- (void)method...`).